# Does jMagick have compare method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, jmagick

I am trying to compare screenshots using the jmagick java api for ImageMagick. I could not find any compare method here http://downloads.jmagick.org/jmagick-doc/
Could someone let me know, if jMagick has a compare or equivalent method or else what did they use instead to compare the images ??